# Detect if an iPhone app with given Apple ID and Bundle ID is already installed

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to detect if an app with the given Bundle ID and Apple ID is already installed on the device? The app does not implement a custom URL Scheme.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit. Why do you need this? and what are you talking about with the custom URL scheme question?

Comment: Derek, one way to detect whether an app is installed or not is to use `UIApplication`'s instance method `canOpenURL`, but the targeted app has to implement at least one custom URL scheme for that and you need to know what it is. That does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness - the answer is no.

Comment: @Apple and #iOS - please do something about it. Hint: Android's Package Manager API. canOpenURL is not universal and works (or doesn't work) differently for various apps